# Python Code to check the minimum TLS version of the Server

Tags: ssl

I am trying to build a code to check the TLS version of the servers. We have some servers whose TLS version are using v1.0 as a minimum requirement but those can still negotiate with v1.2.

I am trying to check which are all our servers who still negotiate with v1.0

Comment: *"I am trying to check which are all our servers who __still negotiate with v1.0__"*  is very different to *"... check the __minimum TLS version__ of the Server"* , so please make clear what you really want to know. Apart from that successful handshake not only depends on the protocol version but also on the ciphers in the client - if the client uses a protocol supported by the server but does not support the right ciphers it will fail. Sou you need to know what clients you care about and what ciphers they support.

Comment: *"Python Code to ...."* - SO is not a code writing service, but about helping others to solve the problem. Show what you did so far and where you've failed. If you want to check if you can connect to a server using a specific TLS version see the `ssl_version` argument in [ssl.wrap_socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket). But again - this will also fail if the client does not support the ciphers the server expects even if both support TLS 1.0.